# I'm having trouble installing OCRopy, I want to use it to create train data for an old manuscript in latin. What prereqs are needed and lines to write

Tags: opencv, github, ocr, tesseract, training

So I am new to using Ubuntu and I am trying to install OCRopy to make train data with the end goal of creating a transcript for a 15th c. manuscript. So far I am considering that my problem may be a lack of prerequisites. I have installed python3 with opencv, scipy, PIL, and numpy.

I tried following the code on this link, https://github.com/ocropus/ocropy , to install dependencies system wide. Having no luck so far any suggestions would be appreciated. Am I missing something else that needs to be installed or should I be using a python virtual environment or Conda instead.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.